# Rails production server (thin): pages occasionally load slower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I'm running my Rails application through `thin` on `Windows OS`.

```
thin start -e production
```

Since the number of users grew, now around 10 people using the app simultaneously, there are times when a same page takes a while longer to load.

- Are there other configurations that I need to set when running the server on production?

I'm quite sure that it has to do with the server since the slow down happens on pages that normally loads fast.

Comment: You'll need to quantify this a little - For example: how  often, how much slower? It is slower because of database queries, time to render the page, waiting for thin to be ready for the next request, something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following document describes about how to deploy rails application in windows. I haven't done this personally but, believe the latest versions should allow that. Please check the below link to see how it can be done

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers/

Answer (score 3):

The Thin webserver is not meant to production environment. Instead of this you should use a different webserver and application server like Nginx/Unicorn, Nginx/Passenger.

Comment: I found out that both web servers don't work on Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) to run your rails app as fast as possible in production mode.

The thin webserver is very fast for few requests, but if there are simultaneously requests, thin gets very slow.